# PDO:: What's wrong with this query?

Tags: php, pdo

Method in my class does it work properly. Don't give me some error message, but simply does not work.

```
        public function query($value)
            {
                $this->__error = FALSE;

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ".Input::input($value);

                        if ($this->__query = $this->__pdo->query($sql))
                        {
                             $this->__result = $this->__query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $this->__count = $this->__query->rowCount(); //Here is the problem

                        }


                    else {
                    $this->__error = TRUE;
     }   
     return $this;
                }

     public function count()
            {
                return $this->__count;
  }
```

But I would not write whole class code, I mention that PDO DataBase connection is properly defined (**$_*pdo property***), also the instance who is responsible to comunicate with database. (**$_instance property**). Input class too.

Here is my index.php (some kind of registration form):

```
    <?php 

    spl_autoload_register(function($class) //Load all class in project
    {
       require_once 'class/'.$class.'.php';
    }
        );

    $user = DataBase_class::instance()->query("username"); //username is the name of textbox

    if ($user->count())
    {
        echo 'User exist';
    }
    else echo 'User not exist';
?>
```

Result is "User not exist", although user exist 100%.

Comment: shouldn't the user be quoted as string

Comment: You shouldn't really build your query like that.  Use parameters for input values and then bind them when executing.

Answer (score 3):

You forget the quotes

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".Input::input($value) . "'";
```

but you should consider to use prepared statements..

```
$stmt = $this->__pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :name");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', Input::input($value));
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Tnx man a lot for your questions! You've helped me with prepare statement!